# Duda con append de JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola tengo un Ajax que me devuelve una información y la utilizo para construir unos desplegables donde tienen que rellenar información.

Pero tengo dos problemas, el primero que añado un botón abajo cuando cargo las filas que para empezar le pongo un `alert()` pero no funciona, y la parte de añadir foto tampoco a pesar de que tienen una id dinamica.

Se aceptan optimización de código, no controlo mucho JavaScript y puede que haya mucho código residual.

Gracias

```
$.ajax({
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: {'tipos': JSON.stringify(tipos),
                   'permutas': JSON.stringify(permutas), 
                   'Producto': producto,
                   'Descripcion': descripcion,
                   'ID': idProducto,
                   'Categoria': categoria,
                   'Proveedor': proveedor,
                   'Referencia': referencia,
                   'Subcategoria': subcategoria,
                   'Foto': foto,
                   'Tipo': tipo,
                   'Estado': estado,
                   'precio': precio,
                   'oferta': oferta },     
            success: function(data){
                if( !data.success ){
                    toastr.success( "Combinaciones completadas", "Perfecto!");
                    $("#respuesta").val(data.producto.id);/*Esto es para traer el ID del producto, para poder modificarlo*/
                    var boton = `<a class="btn btnGuardar guardaVariaciones" id="guardaCombinaciones" data-id="">Guardar atributos</a>`;

                    for (var i = 0; i < data.permutaciones.length; i++) {
                        var id = data.permutaciones[i].id;
                        var productoid = data.permutaciones[i].product_id;
                        var combinacion = data.permutaciones[i].combination;
                        var precio = data.permutaciones[i].precio;
                        var oferta = data.permutaciones[i].oferta;
                        
                        var a = $(`
                        
                        <div id="accordion">
                            <div class="cardCollapse">
                                <button class="btn btn-link collapsed btnCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse${id}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse${id}">
                                    <div class="card-header" id="heading${id}">
                                        <h5 class="mb-0">      
                                            Producto <span style="color: #427ff2;top: 0px;font-weight: 700!important;">#${productoid}</span>
                                        </h5>
                                        <span class="pull-right spanCollapse">${combinacion}</span>
                                    </div>
                                </button>
                          
                              <div id="collapse${id}" class="collapse fondoCollapse" aria-labelledby="heading${id}" data-parent="#accordion">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <div class="row rowDotted">
                                        <div class="col-6">
                                            <div class="eFoto">    
                                                <span style="position: relative">
                                                    <img id="holder${id}" src="{{ asset('images/no-foto.jpg') }}" alt="" class="imgEditPerf334">
                                                    <a data-input="thumbnail${id}" data-preview="holder${id}" class="lfm">
                                                        <i class="fas fa-pen editaFotoProducto334"></i>
                                                    </a>  
                                                </span>
                                                <input id="thumbnail${id}" class="form-control formNuevo" type="hidden" name="imagen" value="" required>   
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-6">
                                            <div class="form-group" style="position:relative;">
                                                <label for="">Referencia</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control myinputs" name="refeJava" id="precio" value="" autocomplete="off" required>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-6">
                                            <div class="form-group" style="position:relative;">
                                                <span class="simboloMedida556">€</span>
                                                <label for="">Precio normal</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control myinputs" name="precio" id="precio" value="${precio}" autocomplete="off" required>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-6">
                                            <div class="form-group" style="position:relative;">
                                                <span class="simboloMedida556">€</span>
                                                <label for="">Precio ofertado</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control myinputs" name="oferta" id="oferta" value="${oferta}" autocomplete="off" required>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          
                        </div>`);
                        $("#permutas").append(a);
                        
                        
                    }
                    $("#permutas").append(boton);
                    console.log(data);
                }
            },
            error: function(data){
                toastr.success( "Revisa las combinaciones", "Algo salio mal!");
            }
        });
```

La parte que digo que no funciona de las fotos es:

```
<div class="eFoto">    
    <span style="position: relative">
      <img id="holder${id}" src="{{ asset('images/no-foto.jpg') }}" alt="" class="imgEditPerf334">
      <a data-input="thumbnail${id}" data-preview="holder${id}" class="lfm">
          <i class="fas fa-pen editaFotoProducto334"></i>
      </a>  
    </span>
    <input id="thumbnail${id}" class="form-control formNuevo" type="hidden" name="imagen" value="" required>   
</div>
```

Para la carga de fotos lo estoy haciendo con Laravel Filemanager, de hecho tengo un añadir en HTML plano y funciona correctamente. No se si al meterlo con `append` no carga su libreria o algo.

Comment: El problema está al definir `var a = $( 'bloque html multilinea inmenso');` pues ese bloque está siendo presentado como un selector y de hecho no puede serlo. Bastaría hacer algo como `var a = 'el bloque inmenso';` y luego hacer el append. Observa que se elimina **$(** y **)**. Una nota adicional: ¿Que es **toastr** ? nunca he visto ese objeto y no lo encontré en la documentación de javascript.

Comment: Hola @quevedo gracias por tu respuesta, lo he probado hacer `var a = 'el bloque inmenso';` y luego `$("#permutas").append(a);` pero sigue sin funcionar el botón y lo de las fotos, puede ser porque lo pongo entre las comillas ` `

Comment: Ignoro lo de las comillas. Nunca he manejado cadenas grandes escritas directamente en javascript. En mi caso todo lo que sea grande llega del servidor. Pero, me interesa y voy a consultar

Comment: Acabo de consultar. Esas comillas no son válidas. Debes usar **'** o **"** [ver manual - Text_formatting](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Text_formatting). Usa comillas simples porque dentro de los bloques van dobles al establecer atributos.

Comment: Adicionalmente, id="acordion" está dentro de un ciclo for de modo que se van a crear varios objetos con el mismo id, **eso no es válido**.

Comment: Hola @quevedo perdona que no pude contestar antés. `Toastr` es una biblioteca para postrar notificaciones en JavaScript, es súper util cuando haces algún ajax para notificar si el resultado fue correcto o no. Por otro lado si no pongo ese tipo de comillas, como hago valido la cadena HTML??

Comment: Dices que usas laravel, luego tienes php de fondo. Puedes preparar ese bloque dentro de una variable del tipo `$mivar = <<<KEY muchas líneas KEY; ` teniendo en cuenta que el KEY de cierre y su punto y coma sean los únicos caracteres en su renglón (línea final), Esa notación interpreta las variables que se escriban dentro de sus líneas.

Comment: Ups, eso no se como se hace @quevedo no tengo ni idea.. Pero el botón ya lo he echo funcionar ya que estaba fuera del `if` pero por que no funciona lo de las imagenes si tienen numeraciones distintas?

Comment: Revisa el ciclo for hay algo que debe estar fuera o se genera un id en conficto `<div id="accordion">` y seguramente el resto queda mál anidado, pues al hacer append, todo se anida bajo ids redundantes (creería que se pisan)

Comment: La representación que me hace el código en el firebug, me sale bien montado y las Ids de forma correcta! podemos hablar por chat por favor¿ @quevedo para no llenar esto?

Comment: Me encuentras allí. Me demoro en aparecer, estoy respondiendo una pregunta

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112490/discussion-between-miguel-and-quevedo).

Answer (score 0):

el problema ocurre acá, no es la utilización correcta de jquery ya que estas mandarle un socotroco de código, recoda que es conveniente y hasta donde yo se, que este código "$()" solo acepta elementos, id, clases y atributos. después no sabría decirte si lo que hiciste esta bien. pero pravo esto y confirma nuestras dudas.

```
var a = $("#id"); // o esta forma
var a = $(".clase"); // o esta forma
```

y para pasar dicha cantidad de texto en ese string que armaste te convendría utilizar

```
var a = `todos tus divs y texto que conoces`; // lo que queres agregar en limpio
 $("#permutas").append(a); // el id de donde lo agregas
```

podría funcionar, como ultimo también podrías utilizar , el div padre que tenes dentro y pasarle un .html() de jquery con la cadena que querías enviarle de html, podría ser otra opció,